# Finding minimum number of inspection points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, network, geometric-network, pipe-network

I am working on a pipeline inspection project and there is a high liklihood that some inspection tool deployment/retrieval station will need to be installed on the pipe network.  the problem is determining the best places to locate the stations.  Analytically it would seem that I am looking for a minimum set of loactions **P** such that the network distance **l** between any two points "adjacent" p<sub>i</sub>, p<sub>j</sub> to eachother on the network is less than or equal to a given distance **L**

**P** = min{ **p**(x,y) | **l**(p<sub>i</sub>,p<sub>j</sub>) <= **L** }

I am at a loss as to where to start in solving this problem.

Comment: This is probably a bit too broad for one question, and should be broken down into parts. Additionally, the locations will likely be driven more by feasibility and system layout rather than just the distance between launcher/receiver. I'd start with identifying the groups of the pipelines that will be inspected (systems), then research the areas that it would actually be possible to install a station at. At that point you may want to continue to do an analysis to determine which sites to use.

Comment: I understand that the network connectivity should be its own question so I removed it from this one.  What other ways would you break up this problem?

Comment: I have already narrowed down my system to what will be inspected and am addressing feasability to weight perfered locations but I am also looking for a general solution to be applied to any geometric network.

I think this sort of question woukld be of great use for many people